# JCodeModel declaring a field with dotted class as type

Tags: java, jcodemodel

I'm using JCodeModel for auto generating some code.

At some point, the code model seems to declare all of my String types as:

```
java.lang.String someFieldName;
```

I came across this problem a few times and solved it myself (one possible reason is declaring a field or a method argument that it's name is beginning with a capital letter) .

This time i don't see the reason.

Anyone know what possibly can cause the code model to declare it that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ref method. This should import the String class in the import section.

```
jCodeModel.ref(String.class)
```